# /My/path bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I just followed [This Guide](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/3-syntax-highlighting/).

Installed Jekyll:

```
$ gem install jekyll
Successfully installed jekyll-3.2.1
Parsing documentation for jekyll-3.2.1
Done installing documentation for jekyll after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But now when I try to run a command from prompt such as:

`jekyll` or `jekyll --help`. it gives that message:

> bash: /g/Arquivos e Programas/Ruby23-x64/bin/jekyll: "G:/Arquivos: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

And if I go through that path, it has 2 files named `Jekyll`.
A normal file and a bash file.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something wasn't prepared for a path with spaces in it. Spaces in paths are very common on Windows, but not at all common on Unix for this very reason.

Bash was trying to run `/g/Arquivos e Programas/Ruby23-x64/bin/jekyll` which it interpreted as run the program `/g/Arquivos` with the arguments `e`, and `Programas/Ruby23-x64/bin/jekyll`. It would have to be quoted like, `'/g/Arquivos e Programas/Ruby23-x64/bin/jekyll'` or the spaces escaped like `/g/Arquivos\ e\ Programas/Ruby23-x64/bin/jekyll`

The simple fix is to install Ruby to a path with no spaces in it. Like `G:\Ruby\`.

The proper fix... well, there's likely to be a TON of places which will be broken by a path with spaces in it. [Report the bug to jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/new).

Comment: Just installed in a location without spaces and BINGo. Thanks, bro !  
I thought I could work around spaces using ` " "  ` or `  ' ' `, but you cant ;p